# Sql Server Cursor error on 'for'

Tags: sql, cursor

here's the sql code I have for a cursor I need:

```
declare @myCursor cursor for
    SELECT item_one, item_2, lastUpdateTime, content_value FROM #MyTable;
```

I'm getting the error:

`Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 44 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'for'.`

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: YOu do know that it is a poor practice to use cursors when you can use set-based logic which is possible most of the time.  If you are doing any kind of an insert/update or delete, please don't use a cursor.

Comment: @HLGEM  I understand it's poor practice, but with the content I'm having to work with I can't see any other way around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cursors do not use a `@` prefix like other variables:

```
declare myCursor cursor for
    SELECT item_one, item_2, lastUpdateTime, content_value FROM #MyTable;
```

Comment: but when I remove the `@` prefix i get this error: `Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 171 Must declare the scalar variable "@target_cursor".`

Comment: @shadonar That's an error relating to a portion of your cursor not shown, can you add the entire cursor to your question?  If `@target_cursor` is the name of your cursor just make sure to change all instances of the name to exclude the `@`.

Comment: nevermind, this fixed the issue, I just happened to have later on another use of @myCursor...  sorry, thanks for the help!!